# Is it possible to access an internal serial port from UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp, serial-port

I develop an UWP app which I will run only on my own Windows 10 IOT enterprice PC. From this App I want to access an internal com port on my PC. However since it is an UWP app and the com port is internal I cannot access it due to the following description from Microsoft:

> Serial ports marked as internal to the machine
> (DEVPKEY_Device_InLocalMachineContainer == TRUE) are not accessible
> unless explictly marked by the vendor driver as unrestricted
> (DEVPKEY_DeviceInterface_Restricted == TRUE). Devices connect via most
> PCI COM port expansion cards are therefore not accessible.

Is it possible to make some setting in the register editor or similar to get around this? Since it is my own computer I have full control of makeing changes to the PC, but I am not able to change the com-port driver.

My function to access a com port works if I use a USB-com port adapter but I want to use the com port already on my PC.
It also works if I make a bridge connection and make a FullTrustProcess call to a separate console-application, that in its turn communicate to the serial port. But still, I would prefer to communicate directly to the serial port from my UWP app.

Comment: Looks like you are at the mercy of the driver vendor. Which driver (make, brand, vendor)  is used for that internal com port?

Comment: The driver provider in my case is Microsoft. So it feels like a dead end if there is no workaround in some way.